# Request for Statistics textbook

Tags: statistics, reference-request

I am looking for a textbook on Statistical Analysis. Unfortunately most of the books I have seen, such as Statistics by DeGroot et al., are quite the opposite of the terse and lean textbooks I prefer (such as any book by Milnor).

Can someone suggest to me an introductory or perhaps even intermediate statistics textbook which is under 300 pages. It can assume that I know measure theory but not much probability theory (though I doubt that would be necessary).

The textbook should teach me enough statistical analysis as is required in an (Business/Financial) Analysts job.

Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Are you looking for an applied statistics textbook? If so, then stats.stackexchange may be the right place to check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)

Answer (score 3):

I like Nitis Mukhopadhyay's [Probability and Statistical Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824703790). But that's just a starting point. It's impossible to tell what exactly you would need for a Business/Financial Analysis job, but probably more than what can be covered in a single introductory textbook.