# Statistics primer for Social Sciences?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, self-learning

I'm a Psychology Major intending to take University level Statistics starting in the Fall.

As I'm a mature student, I've been out of school for about 7 years, and it's been at least that long since I've done any Math related work at any level.

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest some decent books that would be an appropriate primer for someone re-entering Math from a Social Science standpoint? Basically, I'm looking for something to give me a head start on getting back into Math after such a long time away from it, in hopes of not failing my Statistics courses ^^;

Thanks!

Comment: What are the pre-requirements? There are varying levels, such as just algebra (in which case, you should be fine) to multivariate calculus.

Comment: If it's just intro Stats you'll mostly need to familiarize yourself with basic algebra: being comfortable with the order of operations and knowing how to rearrange equations to solve for the unknown. You'll have to have a good understanding of how percentages work. Also maybe knowing how to find the area of a 2-dimensional shape. Googling led me to [Basic Math and Pre-Algebra for Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/basic-math-prealgebra-for-dummies-cheat-sheet.html) which looks like it covers the right type of math for intro-level stats.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, both of you. To clarify, the course pre-requisites are stated as: grade XI or grade XII academic mathematics or equivalent, or [College level Algebra course] with a grade of C or higher. 

I actually have Grade XI academic Math (this is for a Canadian university, if it matters), but as mentioned, I've been away from my studies for a while and may be rusty :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of social sciences involves statistics and probability. [Here](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-best-books-to-learn-probability.html) is a list of books that may help.