# Suggestions for a good statistics book and a calculus book?

Tags: calculus, statistics, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am studying machine learning and I am very interested in going into depth. I feel without good knowledge of differential calculus and statistics, it is very difficult to have perfection. I want to know about very good books on statistics and calculus where topics goes from school level to engineering level. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: No matter what, it is very difficult to have perfection.

Comment: ^Indeed sir!  :)

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes you are right but atleast i can do better with good book rather than bad book

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)

Answer (score 1):

For calculus books, have a look at http://math-blog.com/2007/05/13/the-most-enlightening-calculus-books/ and http://dasgupab.faculty.udmercy.edu/calc-books.html .

For statistics books, have a look at http://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/1q45xj/whats_a_good_book_for_learning_statistics/ .

Comment: thanx for replying so fast.

Comment: ^No problem @omjit. If you think an answer is helpful in this site, please do upvote it, and accept one answer (By clicking the tick mark just below the upvote/downvote option) as your best answer to a question. All the best!

Comment: @Downvoter please explain yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For calculus books two books from my side are the best:
Michael Spivaks calculus
Tom M Apsotols calculus both volume 1 and 2