# Best Statistics Textbook For Undergrad Statistics Course

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm currently an applied math major on the final semester. Currently taking mathematical statistics which im finding difficult. Can anyone recommend a really good textbook with proper worked examples and possibly detailed chapter/section explanations. Im currently using Introduction to Mathematical Statistics - Robert Hogg 7E. Any good recommendations truly appreciated.

Comment: I used Probability and Statistics from Degroot in undergrad which I liked. There is a good amount of examples and explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)