# Book Recommendations on Statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am a robotics student and I would like to master Statistics before diving into machine learning and artificial intelligence. Any book suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)

Answer (score 1):

The cartoon guide to statistics is a fun and visually delightful way to learn statistics. While it seems a little immature it actually covers up to moderately advanced statistics. #1 choice!  [Amazon link here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062731025)

Elementary Statistics is also a good start

taking it further you might try the IB higher maths section on statistics.