# Best books for learning statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm in college level and started reading statistics.
What will be the best books for me?

Here are a few topics that are included in my syllabus,

- Probability
- Central Tendency
- Measures of Disperson
- Random Variable and Probability Distribution

  - Binomial Distribution
  - Poisson Distribution

Comment: I know the answer give a great set of links, but I might add that [this book](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/91cf/33d456e68648d4323a27afccaab05afda435.pdf) is a little newer and provides some nice worked examples too!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)

Answer (score 2):

Probability is a very fuzzy concept for beginners. Starters are always intimidated by formal notations and seemingly disconnected ideas.

The key to the rapid progress in probability is to start by understanding counting and combinatorics. Often professors will tell you not to study combinatorics very deep as his course doesn't require that much. But, the truth is, combinatorics is the most crucial part of understanding probability.

- [Combinatorics a Guided Tour](https://www.scribd.com/doc/244307910/Combinatorics-a-Guided-Tour-David-Mazur) by  David Mazur.

When you are done with combinatorics, study the following books sequentially.

- [Schaum's Outline of Probability](https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/schaums-probability.pdf) by Seymour Lipschutz.
- [Schaum's Outline of Probability, Random Variables, and Random
  Processes](https://www.dca.ufrn.br/~affonso/FTP/livros/Hsu_probabilidade.pdf) by Hwei P. Hsu, Ph.D.
- [Schaum's Outline Probability and
  Statistics](http://www.carlospitta.com/Courses/Estadistica/PDF/Schaum%27s%20Outline%20of%20Probability%20and%20Statistics,%20Third%20Edition%202009.pdf) by Spiegel, Schiller, Srinivasan.

The first one will help you to develop basic understandings. The second one will teach you formal notations and theoretical aspects of Probability. The third one will complete your knowledge of probability and statistics.

If you find trouble understanding concepts during studying the books, go to YouTube and watch corresponding tutorial videos. There are [thousands of them](https://www.youtube.com/user/jbstatistics).

Comment: [Links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer. Please support your answer by explaining why these links are useful to the OP.

Comment: I strongly disagree that combinatorics are necessary to understand probability theory.

Comment: @Math_QED, when I started, I also disagreed.

Comment: I'm talking about measure theoretic probability. Nothing applied. About what are you talking?

Comment: @Math_QED, the applied one.

Comment: Then, I can agree with you!

Answer (score 0):

I really like ["All of Statistics"](https://www.amazon.com.br/All-Statistics-Concise-Statistical-Inference/dp/0387402721) by L. Wasserman